# Не получается правильно разделить диски на новом сервере

Tags: linux, devops

На установленном VPS от Contabo требуется произвести правильный раздел дисков/разделов. По- умолчанию вся память (400G) распределяется между двумя разделами (sda1/sda2). Но мне нужно создать раздел с типом xfs, а сделать я этого не могу. Как только не пробовал через fdisk. Не получается(

Comment: что именно не получается? мало информации. приведи выхлоп lsblk, 
fdisk - для разметки дисков, для создания файловой системы на выделенном разделе используется  mkfs

Comment: «xfs» — это не «тип раздела», а название файловой системы. ну а «тип раздела» можете использовать, например, «[83](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#List_of_partition_IDs)».

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin не видел ни разу чтоб тип раздела влиял на чтото)

Comment: @eri, от балды выставленный тип раздела отрицательно влияет на психическое здоровье коллег, запускающих `fdisk -l`